# Force Directed Layout in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am having some troubles in implementing Force Directed Layout in Haskell. The algorithm is based on considering the entire graph as a physical system, the force are applied to the nodes , pulling them closer or pushing them further apart. Quite new to Haskell, so can you tell me which module to draw graph, objects, to visual things in Haskell. Or some idea to start with this algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which module to draw graph

Perhaps [graphviz](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphviz), or for a more complete solution, you might try [force-layout](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/force-layout), the first hit on Google for "force layout haskell".

Comment: I tried to install the package force-layout by using : cabal install force-layout. But the installation process always stopped at the line: `src/Physics/ForceLayout.hs:104:1:`. I dont' know why, but have sent this bug to the author of this package. I am wonder whether I can download this package and install it manually? I saw some in tar, and zip file, but when open them, they don't have some kind of : make, build, configure. How can I install it manually?

Comment: @chipbk10 Yes, it's pretty easy. The usual order is something like "cabal unpack force-layout; cd force-layout; cabal install", though there are many variations on this. Check out the cabal-install manual for more information.